# NSIS can not load gdiplus.dll in windows XP

Tags: windows, gdi+, nsis

I have make an installer with NSIS , it work fine in windows 7,but when it comes to windows xp system , the UI can not show because my installer needs to load Gdiplus.dll ,and in my xp computer , there is a key in the registry ,which specify a path where to load the gdiplus.dll , but in that path ,there is no gdiplus.dll file , and it just give up and never find the dll I provided,so what's the solution,how can I tell it to load the dll I provide? By the way ,the API LoadLibrary didn't work.

Comment: Which NSIS component requires GDI+? Could you show us your LoadLibrary code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about installing it as prerequisite at installer startup? GdiPlus.dll is part of VC runtime, isn't it? Or you can copy file by yourself (some specific version) to $TEMP directory and load it from there.

I am not sure NSIS installer really needs this file as it is pure C/C++ code. 
Maybe some of your plug-in needs it or some 3rd party code?

Please be specific and tell us more.

Comment: Yes , it's my plug-in which need Gdiplus.dll , and I try to copy it to $TEMP directory and load ,but as I've said ,it doesn't work , LoadLibrary fail and GetLastError return 127, the prerequisite solution has been tried too ,it's so weird, it seems that  it  loads gdiplus.dll just from that specific path,even I remove the registry item

Comment: @godmanzheng: What you are exactly trying to do with GDI call inside NSIS? Can you elaborate? If it's required by your installed application then you should install VC Redist with your installer.